# How to read SAML response coming from idp to get the user being logged into the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sap-fiori, cloudfoundry-uaa, sap-cloud-platform

I am new to server-side application development in SAP Cloud Platform and Nodejs. I have configured SAP identity authentication service as an identity provider with the sub-account in SAP Cloud Platform cockpit. My MTA(UI5+Nodejs) application deployed in cloud foundry sub-account uses UAA service for authentication. Now when I access the application it redirects me to IDP for authentication. After successful authentication, I can see my application home page. I want to identify the user who has logged into the application. The user details are passed as assertion attributes from IDP in SAML response. I can see the user details like id, name in SAML response in chrome developer tools. I am struggling to read the response to find the user id. I am using Nodejs for server-side and SAP UI5 for the front end. As I am new to Nodejs looking some pointers/help to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to obtain the logged in user details from the node.js server (which I assume, is bound to an XSUAA service)

You need to validate the JWT token using `@sap/xssec` and `passport` to obtain the user details. It can be accessed in your express.js route using

```
req.user.id //Get the current user ID
req.authInfo //Can be used to check scope authorizations etc.
```

For instance:

```
...
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('Logged-In user: ' + req.user.id);
});
...
```

For implementation, refer [this page](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/3a8e4372f8e74d05b4ed03a484865e08.html)